# How can i retrieve child(name and list_image)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve name and list_image from List child of a Basic child.
 Here I am taking an id from the previous card to retrieve the inside information but I am not able to retrieve the data, can't find the actual problem.

[image]

```
public class fund_list extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference listref_basic, listref_advanced;
String FundId = "";
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
RecyclerView list_recyclerview;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fund_list);


    listref_basic = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Basic");
    //listref_advanced = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Advanced");

    list_recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list_RecyclerView);
    list_recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    list_recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    if (getIntent() != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "inside 1st if statement ");
        FundId = getIntent().getStringExtra("FundId");
    }
    if (!FundId.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "inside 2nd if statement ");
        getList(FundId, listref_basic);
    }

    }

private void getList(String fundId, DatabaseReference DR) {
    DR.child(fundId).child("List");
    Log.i(TAG, "inside getlist method ");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<List> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<List>()
                    .setQuery(DR, List.class)
                    .build();
    Log.i(TAG, "after options ");
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<List, List_holder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull List_holder holder, int position, @NonNull List model) {
            holder.setName(model.getName());
            holder.setList_image(getApplicationContext(), model.getList_image());
            Log.i(TAG, "inside onbind");
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public List_holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_card, parent, false);

            return new List_holder(view);

        }
    };
    list_recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.i(TAG, "after set adapter ");

}
```

here is the image of firebase which i've been trying to retrieve.

Comment: your FundId is empty

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this snippet:

```
DR.child(fundId).child("List");
Log.i(TAG, "inside getlist method ");

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<List> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<List>()
                .setQuery(DR, List.class)
                .build();
```

You're not storing the result of `DR.child(fundId).child("List")` anywhere, so when you pass `DR` into `setQuery` it is just pointing to `Basic`.

The solution is to store the reference to the user's list and pass that into your `FirebaseRecyclerOptions`:

```
DatabaseReference usersListReference = DR.child(fundId).child("List");
Log.i(TAG, "inside getlist method ");

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<List> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<List>()
                .setQuery(usersListReference, List.class)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // retrieve the data    
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        ref.child("Basic").child("01").child("List").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
// do something here
  }

  @Override
  public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

  @Override
  public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

  @Override
  public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```